# Laravel 5 save to database and return id

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to use the eloquent save whilst returning the id of the tuple using

```
$var=$data->save();
```

Then trying to return the primary key.Now my primary key is called `company_id` but when i run:-

```
$id=$data->company_id
```

It throws an error saying

> column 'id'doesnt exist in the company table.

why does company_id get renamed to id.

Comment: Can you share the model code

Comment: `$id` is empty. because you save data from DB using some other ways. you should used  `insertGetId` method for get autoIncrement ID (primary key) from DB. below  i have post my answer with details

Answer (score 1):

place it in your model

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'company_id';
```

Comment: the solution u gave worked for one table . i made similar changes to other tables as well..
but the other tables still return id instead of the proper name of the primary key.

Comment: -- this is my model--
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class category extends Model
{

    protected $primary_key='cat_id';
    protected $fillable=[
        
        'scheme_code',
        'cat_name',


    ];

    protected $table = 'categories';
}

--- my controller code where i save---
$temp_category->scheme_code=$last_inserted_mf;
        $temp_category->cat_name=$category;
        $temp_category->save();

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertGetId` method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID

here is the example

```
$id = DB::table('tableName')->insertGetId(
          ['name' => $request->input('name'),
           'address'=> $request->input('address')]
);
print_r($id);
```